# How can I do an sql Union on multiple Linq IQueryables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, concatenation

I'm working on a project where I want to make a graphs out of logdata.

So I've got my logdata loaded in my sql server and found the query that produces the results I need. Each log entry contains measured values per 2 seconds.

```
SELECT '7am' as timeslot, MAX(Odometer_km) - MIN(Odometer_km) as distance, AVG(Tanktemperature_C) tanktemp, AVG(Pressure_bar) avgBar FROM [FC66294] 
where [epochasdate] >= '2018-05-03 07:00:00' AND [epochasdate] <= '2018-05-03 08:00:00'
UNION 
SELECT '8am' as timeslot, MAX(Odometer_km) - MIN(Odometer_km) as distance, AVG(Tanktemperature_C) tanktemp, AVG(Pressure_bar) avgBar FROM [FC66294] 
where [epochasdate] >= '2018-05-03 08:00:00' AND [epochasdate] <= '2018-05-03 09:00:00'
UNION 
SELECT '9am' as timeslot, MAX(Odometer_km) - MIN(Odometer_km) as distance, AVG(Tanktemperature_C) tanktemp, AVG(Pressure_bar) avgBar FROM [FC66294] 
where [epochasdate] >= '2018-05-03 09:00:00' AND [epochasdate] <= '2018-05-03 10:00:00'
```

This example shows three timeslots with some calculated values over this timeslot.

Now I'm trying to reproduce this SQL result in C# with a linq query, since I would like to display the results in a graph. I've come up with the following:

```
using (var entity = new DBEntity.Entities())
            {
                var startDatetime = new DateTime(2018, 05, 03, 7, 0, 0);
                var endDatetime = new DateTime(2018, 05, 03, 8, 0, 0);

                var firstResult = entity.M_FC66294
                    .Where(x => x.epochasdate >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(startDatetime, 0) && x.epochasdate <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(endDatetime, 0))
                    .GroupBy(x => 1)
                    .Select(g => new {
                        TankTemp = g.Average(x => x.Tanktemperature_C),
                        Bar = g.Average(x => x.Pressure_bar),
                        MinOdo = g.Min(x => x.Odometer_km),
                        MaxOdo = g.Max(x => x.Odometer_km)
                    });

                var secondResult = entity.M_FC66294
                    .Where(x => x.epochasdate >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(startDatetime, 0) && x.epochasdate <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(endDatetime, 0))
                    .GroupBy(x => 1)
                    .Select(g => new {
                        TankTemp = g.Average(x => x.Tanktemperature_C),
                        Bar = g.Average(x => x.Pressure_bar),
                        MinOdo = g.Min(x => x.Odometer_km),
                        MaxOdo = g.Max(x => x.Odometer_km)
                    });

                var finalQuery = CreateEmptyEnumerable(firstResult);

                for (var i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
                {
                    var result = entity.M_FC66294
                    .Where(x => x.epochasdate >= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(startDatetime, i) && x.epochasdate <= System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddHours(endDatetime, i))
                    .GroupBy(x => 1)
                        .Select(g => new {
                            TankTemp = g.Average(x => x.Tanktemperature_C),
                            Bar = g.Average(x => x.Pressure_bar),
                            MinOdo = g.Min(x => x.Odometer_km),
                            MaxOdo = g.Max(x => x.Odometer_km)
                        });
                    finalQuery = finalQuery.Concat(result);
                }

                var test1 = firstResult.Concat(secondResult).ToList();

                var test2 = finalQuery.ToList();
            }
```

Now the variable test1 actually contains 2 rows of the data that I need. But I would like the variable test2 to contain 24 rows(1 day) of data.

Yet it does not contain any rows.

So, how do I concatenate multiple of the result variables and then run a ToList() on the finalQuery?

Edit: Or how do I use the concat inside the loop?

Comment: What's the difference between the query being sent to the database and the query you were expecting?

Comment: The SQL and C# query should Ideally have the same results, except that I would use several time parameters in the C# version to accomodate for the user request. Also the linq has a groupby, which I used to be able to select aggregated variables in the linq query (I didn't know how else to get these aggregated result).

Comment: I was not asking about the results. I was asking about the query. In what does the query generated by LINQ differs from what you expected/wanted?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this.
The `var test1 = firstResult.Concat(secondResult).ToList();` gets me exactly the result that I want. But it is only two rows of data. 

Basically, the result I would like to have might look like this: 
`var test2 = firstResult.Concat(secondResult).Concat(thirdResult).Concat(untill_i_Result).ToList();`
Except the finalQuery variable seems to not contain any Sql after the loop finished.

Comment: Please, look at the T-SQL sent to the database.

Comment: For the two rows it is a rather long SQL, yes, and it looks completely different from what I wrote myself, but it does get the job done. Do you want me to post it here? Or are you suggesting that it will become to complex?

Comment: Posting the actual linq query seems irrelevant to me. 
I've decided I'm going to use database-views to get my hourly data from the logs and work with simpler linq queries on these views.
Thanks again for taking the time to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about concatenate but you seem to use it so I am not exactly sure what you need but

If you want the 24 records in a variable grouped per hour you could just run a group by on the hour of your data. like this

```
var groupedbyhour = entity.M_FC66294.GroupBy(entry => entry.epochasdate.Date.AddHours(entry.epochasdate.Hour))//group by hour
                           .Select(HourGroup => new
                           {
                              TankTemp = HourGroup.Average(x => x.Tanktemperature_C),
                              Bar = HourGroup.Average(x => x.Pressure_bar),
                              MinOdo = HourGroup.Min(x => x.Odometer_km),
                              MaxOdo = HourGroup.Max(x => x.Odometer_km),
                              epochasdate = HourGroup.Max(x => x.epochasdate.Date.AddHours(x.epochasdate.Hour))
                           }).ToList();
```

Keep in mind the epochasdate would now be groups of hours so it would be for example 2019/07/30 - 7:00 and 2019/07/30 - 8:00

UPDATE

Here is my full test so you can replicate.

```
public class entry
{
    public int Odometer_km;
    public DateTime epochasdate;
    public int Tanktemperature_C;
    public int Pressure_bar;
}
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<entry> entries = new List<entry>(){
            new entry() {epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 7, 2, 1), Odometer_km = 10, Pressure_bar = 1, Tanktemperature_C = 23},
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 7, 1, 1), Odometer_km = 20, Pressure_bar = 2, Tanktemperature_C = 25 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 7, 3, 1), Odometer_km = 22, Pressure_bar = 2, Tanktemperature_C = 24 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 7, 22, 1), Odometer_km = 25, Pressure_bar = 4, Tanktemperature_C = 22 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 8, 24, 1), Odometer_km = 36, Pressure_bar = 2, Tanktemperature_C = 20 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 8, 21, 1), Odometer_km = 42, Pressure_bar = 3, Tanktemperature_C = 19 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 8, 29, 1), Odometer_km = 50, Pressure_bar = 2, Tanktemperature_C = 21 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 8, 22, 1), Odometer_km = 55, Pressure_bar = 4, Tanktemperature_C = 20 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 8, 52, 1), Odometer_km = 62, Pressure_bar = 2, Tanktemperature_C = 19 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 9, 43, 1), Odometer_km = 80, Pressure_bar = 3, Tanktemperature_C = 17 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 9, 22, 1), Odometer_km = 120, Pressure_bar = 1, Tanktemperature_C = 18 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 9, 12, 1), Odometer_km = 140, Pressure_bar = 3, Tanktemperature_C = 16 },
            new entry() { epochasdate = new DateTime(2019, 07, 29, 9, 31, 1), Odometer_km = 156, Pressure_bar = 2, Tanktemperature_C = 17 }
        }; 

        var groupedbyhour = entries.GroupBy(entry => entry.epochasdate.Date.AddHours(entry.epochasdate.Hour))//group by hour
                                   .Select(HourGroup => new
                                   {
                                       TankTemp = HourGroup.Average(x => x.Tanktemperature_C),
                                       Bar = HourGroup.Average(x => x.Pressure_bar),
                                       MinOdo = HourGroup.Min(x => x.Odometer_km),
                                       MaxOdo = HourGroup.Max(x => x.Odometer_km),
                                       MeasureTime = HourGroup.Max(x => x.epochasdate.Date.AddHours(x.epochasdate.Hour))
                                   }).ToList();
    }
}
```

if your epochasdate type is not a datetime and can not be grouped by for some reason use the .addhour and add 0 hours to the value it should return a DateTime result which your groupby feature could understand

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your answer! I tried, but I can't seem to get this linq groupby to run. 
I've build a database view on which I will run my linq queries.

Your answer is what I'm trying to achieve: the group by in sql:
 
`GROUP BY datepart(YEAR, [epochasdate]), datepart(DAYOFYEAR, [epochasdate]), datepart(hour, [epochasdate]);   `

Comment: @Remy thats strange I ran this code and it worked. what is the error you are facing with my code

Comment: Well, the error I got is this: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ‘System.DateTime AddDays(Double)’ method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. Then searching for an answer I found the Entity.DbFunctions. I'm still fiddling with that but no luck yet achieving the groupby.

Comment: Alright, I got it :D `.GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.epochasdate.Year, x.epochasdate.Month,x.epochasdate.Day, x.epochasdate.Hour,0,0))` is what I need.